# Can't load oracle.so

Tags: oracle, perl

I am getting this exception:

```
Can't load '/usr/perl/lib/site_perl/5.8/x86_64-linux/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory at
/.../perl/lib/5.8/x86_64-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 169
```

If I do ls -ltr /.../perl/lib/site_perl/5.8/x86_64-linux/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so I see that the file is there. The process I am running also sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH before attempting to connect. A build and deploy on another machine doesn't produce the same error and runs fine. Running uname -sm gives Linux x86_64 on both machines. Is there something else that could cause this error?

Comment: Are the permissions of that file identical on both machines?

Comment: Yes, I also tried sudo chmod 777 Oracle.so just to make sure it wasn't the issue.

Comment: What is on line 169 of the DynaLoader.pm file? `cat -n DynaLoader.pm | grep ^169`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `DBD::Oracle`'s `Oracle.so` is trying to open `libclntsh.so.8.0` and can't find it. So you need to find out if that version of the shared library is installed.

Perform the following command:

```
$ locate libclntsh.so
```

You should get a list of files beginning with `libclntsh.so`.  If you are lucky , `libclntsh.so.8.0` will be among the results, and then you'll need to make sure that the directory that it lives in  is on you load path.  For instance my server has:

```
 $ locate libclntsh.so
 /home/oracle/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so
 /home/oracle/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1
 /home/oracle/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
```

If `locate` fails completely, you can build the database using `updatedb` or you can try using `find`:

```
 find / -name 'libclntsh.so*' -print
```

Use a pager or redirect stderr to a file because you might end up dealing with a lot of error messages from `find`, which is okay, but using less will allow you to just refresh the screen to see `find`'s output.

Comment: Updating here: This was the correct answer. There were 2 issues:
1) The oracle client did get installed correctly on the server. 2) The application was using an outdated jar. I updated the build and redeployed..

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:
Just pass your Oracle path variables before you run any scripts:
Like for perl you can do add below in beginning of your script:

```
BEGIN {
   my $ORACLE_HOME     = "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64";
   my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "$ORACLE_HOME/lib";
   if ($ENV{ORACLE_HOME} ne $ORACLE_HOME
   || $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ne $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ) {
      $ENV{ORACLE_HOME}     = "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64";
      $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = "$ORACLE_HOME/lib";
      exec { $^X } $^X, $0, @ARGV;
   }
}
```